# Parse XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am using `SimpleXMLElement` to parse xml in PHP and it is working fine. My xml is like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<app id="123">
   <username>sample</username>
</app>
```

My code is,

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents(file.xml));
foreach($xml->App as $product)
     {
          $user   =   $product->username;
     }
```

It gives correct username "sample" as output.

But now I need to get value of `id` inside the app tag. If I changes the xml format and gives the id inside `<app>` tag as `<id>123</id>`, I can get it simply.

But I cant change the format! Is there a way to get the `id` value within the same format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
     $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents(file.xml));
     foreach($xml->App as $product)
     {
          $user   =   $product->username;
          $id = $product->attributes()->id;
     }
```